# Moving Hibernate app to JBoss - Position beyond number of declared ordinal parameters

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss

i have a Hibernate web app that is currently working on tomcat/CloudFoundry, but when i try to run it on JBoss I am getting some errors.

In my DAO I am creating a query to load Users by userName, as follows:

```
Query query = getEntityManager().createQuery("select u from com.tmm.enterprise.socialcv.security.Account u where u.userName = ?1");
query.setParameter(1, userName);
```

The above works when I run the app on Tomcat, but when I run it on JBoss I get the following error:

```
16:31:47,639 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Handler execution resulted in exception - forwarding to resolved error view: ModelAndView: reference to view with name 'dataAccessFailure'; model is {exception=org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: Position beyond number of declared ordinal parameters. Remember that ordinal parameters are 1-based! Position: 1; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: Position beyond number of declared ordinal parameters. Remember that ordinal parameters are 1-based! Position: 1}: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: Position beyond number of declared ordinal parameters. Remember that ordinal parameters are 1-based! Position: 1; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: Position beyond number of declared ordinal parameters. Remember that ordinal parameters are 1-based! Position: 1
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:301) [org.springframework.orm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.aspectj.JpaExceptionTranslatorAspect.ajc$afterThrowing$org_springframework_orm_jpa_aspectj_JpaExceptionTranslatorAspect$1$18a1ac9(JpaExceptionTranslatorAspect.aj:15) [spring-aspects-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at com.tmm.enterprise.socialcv.security.dao.AccountDAO.loadAccountByUserName(AccountDAO.java:28) [classes:]
    at com.tmm.enterprise.socialcv.service.AccountService.loadAccountByUserName(AccountService.java:48) [classes:]
    at com.tmm.enterprise.socialcv.service.AccountService.setCredentials(AccountService.java:241) [classes:]
    at com.tmm.enterprise.socialcv.controller.HomeController.signup(HomeController.java:59) [classes:]
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: Position beyond number of declared ordinal parameters. Remember that ordinal parameters are 1-based! Position: 1
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.setParameter(QueryImpl.java:446) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.setParameter(QueryImpl.java:67) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    ... 80 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: ***Position beyond number of declared ordinal parameters. Remember that ordinal parameters are 1-based! Position: 1***
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.ParameterMetadata.getOrdinalParameterDescriptor(ParameterMetadata.java:80) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.ParameterMetadata.getOrdinalParameterExpectedType(ParameterMetadata.java:86) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractQueryImpl.determineType(AbstractQueryImpl.java:444) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractQueryImpl.setParameter(AbstractQueryImpl.java:416) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.setParameter(QueryImpl.java:440) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    ... 81 more
```

I have tried changing to both the following queries but still no luck:

```
Query query = getEntityManager().createQuery("select u from com.tmm.enterprise.socialcv.security.Account u where u.userName = ?");
        query.setParameter(0, userName);
```

The above gives me the same error. As does:

```
Query query = getEntityManager().createQuery("select u from com.tmm.enterprise.socialcv.security.Account u where u.userName = ?");
        query.setParameter(1, userName);
```

And switching to named parameters gives me an error about not being able to locate named parameter.

Any ideas? (as an aside, I also had to update the DAO to fully qualified Account in the query on JBoss - on tomcat it was working just querying Account)

Answer (score 1):

I fixed such error in that way

```
schema.table = ' ?' ->error

schema.table = '?' ->no error
```

Maybe it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Hibernate HQL [reference](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-expressions), if you use JDBC positional style, you *only* have to use `?`. If you're using named parameters then you should use `:paramName`.

Comment: Yeah, as per the second and third code examples in my original question, I have tried using both the "?" approach and the "?index" approach - neither of which work.  I have also used the named parameters using  the :paramName which also gives an error.

Answer (score 0):

```
query = getEntityManager().createQuery(
"select u from com.tmm.enterprise.socialcv.security.Account u where u.userName = :userName");
query.setParameter("userName", userName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Even in my case nothing was working, I have tried

1. Positional parameter with index 0
2. Positional parameter with index 1
3. Named parameter

Finally I found that parameter list of the resulted query object was empty every time resulting in error while calling `setParameter()`.

Solution: the entity mapping was missing in the `persistence.xml` file, after adding it, it started working!!